# Laptop Ubuntu 16.04 has loss of power during OS startup sequence

Tags: boot, xubuntu, hard-drive

(think I am a total newbie, especially really solving Ubuntu problems,
although copy and paste of code worked sometimes..)

Now during startup of my system, few seconds after showing up the Xubuntu Startup screen, HDD with maximum read operations, there occurs a complete power loss, power lamp still blinking (like standby?).
I press the main power button, screen turns on, laptop continues loading Ubuntu.
After login same failure (power loss/standby) happens once again.
I press main power button, now Xubuntu desktop loads properly.

I have the notion it has something to do with partitions/folders not correctly set up. Please, help!

Here are some things, I did to my laptop/Ubuntu installation:

Hardware
- Had a hardware issue with my HDD, fixed it by replacing HDD connector cable,
 tests in "gnome-disks" and "gparted" didn't give a clue for connection errors

I also disconnected and removed bad internal DVD writer and switched to external USB Logical Drive

Installation
- erased HDD with the tool of RedoBackup "Factory Drive Reset",
 which worked out, telling that some files/areas couldn't be deleted properly

- set up partition table and partitions with gparted,
  also from bootable media
- finally installed Xubuntu, with Ubuntu 16.04, there is no other OS installed!

[Screenshot of Gparted run within the system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMJHf.png)

[Screenshot of kinfocenter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7gNl.png)

For good luck, there is no data in danger, because it's a new setup.

Looking forward..

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue somewhat similar due to a corrupted XServer. Can you logon text only (No XServer) without the issue? I think you can press the Super/Windows button and Function key 5 to get a console. Could be something to look at. Take Care.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, it must not have to do with corrupt hardware, I again made a factory drive reset, this time with no problems, tried to reinstall xubuntu 16.04. I was soon remembered that this kind of power loss, first time happenend during installation, three or four times, dont know how I managed to install Xubuntu 16.04 at all. This time I decided to install Windows XP at first, with no problems, and now I like to try older Xubuntu 14.04 Trusty Tahr as dual boot system, maybe it helps.